# Infobubble in PyGtk

Tags: google-maps, pygtk

I am working on a PyGTK based desktop App . I need a UI component that is similar to infobubble used in Google Maps , i.e.  it displays HTML and adheres to a particular point. I looked for a widget like this , but to no avail . Can any one point out particular GTK widget to look for , as I am new to GTK.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't one in the standard GTK widgets. You might try to write one yourself, or perhaps [Clutter](http://www.clutter-project.org) might be your toolkit of choice...